# Python open file not identifying break line

Tags: json, python-3.x, encode

I'm trying to fix an JSON file that was badly generated, so I need to replace all the '}{' by '},{' and stuff. The problem is that Python stop recognizing '\n' as a break line so when read the files by readlines() it print all the file, the same with ASCII characteres, they are all printed in the file and not recognized as ASCII characteres.

My code

```
def strip_accents(text):
    try:
        text = unicode(text, 'utf-8')
    except (TypeError, NameError): # unicode is a default on python 3 
        print('ai carai')
        pass
    text = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', text)
    text = text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    text = text.decode("utf-8")
    return text


file_name = 'json/get_tweets.json'
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    file_s = ''
    for i in f.readlines():
        print(i)
        i = i.replace('}{','},{')
        i = strip_accents(i)
        file_s += i
file_s = '[' + file_s + ']'
```

My file is around 4GB almost impossible to print here, so there is a print.

[image]

I already tried different encondings, but no result.

Can someone help to find a solution?

**EDIT**: The print wasnt uploaded. Sorry.

Comment: The `.readlines()`, and building up a giant `file_s`, will contribute to a process memory footprint of several gig. There's no need for that, you can read a line at a time with `for i in f:`, and then immediately print() or .write() each line that you've cleaned up. Also, `sed 's/}{/},{/g' < in.json > out.json` would be an easy pre-processing step. Verify there's no invisible character between the braces, if you're having trouble getting the replacement to happen.

Comment: Did not work, still printing the whole file, sorry.

Comment: Sounds like there's hardly any newlines in that file. Once you _do_ obtain some valid JSON, you can use `jq . < in.json` to format it so it's human readable. Tacking on a `\n` newline after each `}` close curly might make it a bit more legible.